# Увага (що ми маємо робити) / Important (what we should do)

Tags: discussion, info, obsolete

Ця рекомендація, здається, більше не актуальна. Щось схоже на нову рекомендацію — [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/147/4). Старий текст наводиться нижче просто для зручності.

This text seems to be no more up-to-date. Something similar to new suggestions is [here](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/147/4). Old text below is just for convenience.

> <sub>Цей текст є спробою донести інформацію до користувачів, а не питанням — тим не менш ви можете висловлювати ваші думки, пропозиції, ідеї у коментарях/відповідях.</sub>
>
> [Ukrainian Language (на Stack Exchange)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) — сайт питань і відповідей про українську мову. Писати питання і відповіді може кожен. Сайт створено на базі платформи Stack Exchange.
>
> Зараз (орієнтовно 7 лютого 2017 — 28 лютого 2017) триває період «приватної бети». В цей період сайт не відкрито широкому загалу і ми маємо наповнити його питаннями і відповідями *самі*. Це має дві мети:
>
> 1. Показати приклад тим, хто заходитиме після закінчення приватної бети.
> 2. **Довести адміністрації Stack Exchange, що наш сайт гідний на відкриття.** Оцінюються такі речі:
>
>    - тема української мови викликає інтерес;
>    - ми попадаємо в формат Stack Exchange;
>    - *ми здатні створювати якісні матеріали*.
>
>      Наприкінці приватної бети адміністрація Stack Exchange вирішуватиме, відкривати наш сайт чи закривати. За ці три тижні ми маємо створити якомога більше *хороших* питань і відповідей.
>
> Всі питання технічного/організаційного плану, будь ласка, ставте [в ме́ті](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/) (бажано дублювати англійською) чи [фейсбук-групі](http://facebook.com/groups/ukrstackexchange/) (будь-якою мовою), а не в основному розділі.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>This text is a try to convey information to users, not a question — still you are allowed to express your thoughts, propositions, ideas within comments/answers.</sub>
>
> [Ukrainian Language (at Stack Exchange)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) is a site for questions and answers about Ukrainian language. Everyone is allowed to write questions and answers. The site is based on the Stack Exchange platform.
>
> As for now (approximately 7 Feb 2017 — 28 Feb 2017) the “private beta” period is on. In that period the site isn't open for the public, and we are to fill it with questions and answers *ourself*. This has two goals:
>
> 1. To show an example for those, who will visit the site after the end of private beta.
> 2. **To prove for Stack Exchange administrators, that our site is worth opening.** The following stuff is examined:
>
>    - the topic (Ukrainian language) has enough interest;
>    - we fit the format of Stack Exchange;
>    - *we are able to create quality information*.
>
>      At the end of private beta the Stack Exchange administrators will decide, whether to open or to close our site. During these three weeks we are to create as much *good* questions and answers as possible.
>
> Please, ask all kinda-technical/organizational questions within the [meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/) (it's desirable to dub into English there) or in [Facebook group](http://facebook.com/groups/ukrstackexchange/) (in any language), not within the main section.

Comment: Вітаю.
Приєднуємось. Хто ми - Українська Друпал Спільнота. Особисто я - менеджер [спільноти перекладачів Друпал Українською](https://localize.drupal.org/) - як бачите - тримаємо марку, на першому місці вже впродовж року. Що вже зроблено
Ми [запустили процедуру перевірки](https://www.facebook.com/groups/104220905217/permalink/10154782842070218/) спірних перекладів, тому дана спільнота нами сприймається як деякий ресурс, відповіді на питання якого будуть використані для вдосконалення перекладів, які вже є в системі.
Аналогічно від нас можете отримувати відгуки і перехресні посилання в тематиках,

Comment: Чи обов'язково за час приватної бети виконати вимогу щодо відвідувань?

Comment: @FireCrosser, звісно, [ні](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290462/252301). На приватній беті оцінюється якість, а не кількість. Якщо Ви про [ці цифри](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language) — то це, взагалі, стосується [умов виходу з публічної бети](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/252301) (а не з приватної) — з чим поспішати необов'язково, бо в публічній беті сайти перебувають *роками* (в публічній беті рідко закривають). Чи яку саме вимогу Ви маєте на увазі?

Comment: @FireCrosser, в приватній беті (~ до 28 лютого) нам рекомендують показати **якість** (а не кількість). В публічній беті (яка буде лише якщо ми пройдемо приватну і може тривати скільки завгодно), щоб не закрили, рекомендують: (а) [Be Nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/252301), (б) не спамити, (в) вчасно виконувати [review](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review) (якщо я правильно розумію фразу "flags to be cleared").

Comment: маю на увазі вимогу про кількість відвідувань сайту (1500 на день). А якщо це про публічну бету – то це чудово. Дякую за інформацію!

Comment: @FireCrosser, а де Ви чули про вимогу "1500 на день"? А, все, [знайшов](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language). Думаю, це не стосується приватної бети. (Бо які можуть бути відвідування, якщо нас ще немає в пошукових системах?) Це, думаю, одна з умов graduation (виходу з публічної бети).